# LaTeX is not compiling consistently

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am really new to LaTeX, so it's possible I'm making some egregious error that I'm not aware of, but my documents are compiling inconsistently.  By that I mean it compiles correctly maybe one in twenty times.  When it does it looks fine, but it rarely does.  I've been sent documents from other people that they have compiled successfully and they get completely ruined.

I'm using these packages in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding=*,family=*}
```

One thing that seems to frequently be going wrong is that the following command

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^n} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=0}^n \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}(-1)^j f(x-jh)
\end{equation}
```

is getting me incomprehensible garbage.  <s>I would post a picture, but I don't have enough reputation points.</s>  The weird thing is that it's fine most of the time.  The font also changes from compilation to compilation.  This is happening across all documents.  Sometimes even viewing a PDF that was written in LaTeX online gets my heaps of crap like this and I have to reload pages a few times before I get anything legible.  Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question to include the image.

Comment: BTW, to help others answer your question, it would help if you posted a "minimal (non)working example"; see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). For example, make a copy of a document that is not compiling correctly, and try to make it as short as possible to illustrate your example. Then post that complete file here, when it is short enough. See the [suggestions at that link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for more.

Comment: What viewer are you using?  Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Does the result change from compilation to compilation on the same computer, or on different computers. If the later, one of the computers might have TeX installation issues such as missing fonts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. Here's a [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`?  Dose the `.log` file contain any error messages/warnings?

Comment: This seems a problem that sometimes happened (happens?) on Mac OS X and is related to the font cache. When it happened to me I tried the methods you find in the last two messages of [this thread in Mac OS Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071026081555971&query=restart+font+server)

Comment: Which fonts do you use? The standard Computer/Latin Modern? Operating system? Pdf viewer? TeX distribution? Your example compiles fine on my machine (TeX Live 2012, up to date; Ubuntu 12.10; Okular, Evince, Adobe Reader)

Comment: Remember that a LaTeX run creates a slew of intermediate files, to be used next time. You have to run LaTeX a few times (2 or 3) and perhaps run external tools (BibTeX, others) to use them to get the final document. Not running the right sequence of comands will give inconsistent results.